# PHP CPU and Memory Usage

Tags: php, laravel, memory, cpu

I am learning PHP and Laravel. The company I work for has a web app built in pure PHP. I have noticed that when doing something like performing a database update from a large CSV file which CPU and memory intensive, pretty much nothing else can be done with the web app. For instance, updating someones account with something insignificant and not CPU and memory intensive at all. Basically doing the former bricks the system until it is done. Looking at `TOP` on the Linux server, shows CPU usage at like 99% and memory usage considerably high.

Anyway, this really isn't an enterprise like system, just something a few users use to manage the users for an another web app written in a Python framework that clients use. But it got me thinking what would be the approach for a PHP based enterprise system?

Obviously can't have a single user performing an intensive task bricking the system until it is done. I imagine there are tons of examples in the real world where PHP is handling very complex memory intensive tasks and it is unnoticeable other users.

EDIT: And when I say "bricking the system" I mean the server itself so both the admin PHP web app and the client Python web app really don't respond to requests.

Comment: About how large is the CSV file? Tens of megabytes..gigabytes? What is the datatype of the column? For just adding a big list of data it should be fast..are you making SQL do any logic or simple INSERT INTO ... ? We need to see code to know why its taking so long.

Comment: The one I am currently working with is  about 17MB, but what SQL is doing is checking to see if the rows exist already in the table, and if not adding them. I didn't write it, but it seems to me the table should just be dropped and a new one created. It looks like they made almost everything `VARCHAR(32)`... and there about 956 columns and 5000 rows.

Comment: I hope its don't check rows one by one.

Comment: Yea, I should really take a look at the query. Still though is there a way to limit the amount of CPU and memory it is using without stopping it running, thus hopefully allowing other users to continue their work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would wager all of my Quatloos that you've got an open session for the long-running request doing database inserts that's preventing subsequent requests from opening the session. What you need to do is:

```
<?php
session_start();

/* pre-game stuff that depends on $_SESSION */

session_write_close();

/* long-running stuff that doesn't need to update $_SESSION */
```

Or better yet just skip opening the session for this task, if possible.

*Addendum:*

1. Fire whoever made that 956-column, varchar-only DB schema.
2. If inserts are that slow I'll bet that someone's gone and added way too many indexes as well.
3. If you're running on the cheapest possible, shared-CPU, public cloud instance you could very well be using up all of your CPU shares. I've redlined a GCE micro instance's CPU just by writing a large file to a fast disk.

Answer (score 3):

In an enterprise system, first thing you deal with is redundancy. Everything has to be redundant. In case of an application based on PHP, the setup is what's crucial.

If we're talking about a website, these are the steps

- DNS is updated so it resolves more than 1 IP. That way it's irrelevant which IP is returned back to the browser or if one of the servers in DNS pool dies first. Amazon's Route 53 is something we use. And it's awesome.
- Next comes web server. When an IP is "hit", the request comes to a web server. We use `nginx` (because `nginx` is - you guessed - awesome). Since there are multiple IP addresses in the DNS pool, there are multiple web servers available. Again, it's irrelevant which web server will deal with client's request - redundancy for the win.
- `nginx` either serves static content or passes the request to PHP if a rule is satisfied. We use `php-fpm`. Each of `nginx` servers proxies the HTTP request to a cluster of `php-fpm` nodes. In regular language - it chooses yet another computer in cluster of computers which serves PHP. It's irrelevant which PHP node will deal with the request - redundancy for the win.
- PHP now does some work, connect to the database and - you guessed - it "speaks" to a cluster of databases. Databases are in sync, there are whole books about this topic, so I won't go into details. Again, it's not relevant which db gets the query - redundancy for the win (there are actually many ways to deal with this).
- Database servers are **optimized** for the type of work they're doing - that means they're optimized for either reading or writing. A database or any kind of storage solution isn't infinite black hole that you can fill in just like that. You have to carefully choose what the server will be doing - will it write? Will it be used for reading? How many writes will it do? How many reads will it do? What's the plan where amount of workload increases? Basically, you need to optimize the database server - you definitely **can't** use default MySQL config. If you have extensive workloads that might overburden the db, you use a queueing mechanism that's able to collate multiple inserts and flush them in a single transaction - that method utilizes hard disks' bandwith and trades it off for I/O (basically, that means it's good and works fast).

So, there you go. This is a short overview how you'd approach something of enterprise level in PHP. Every piece should be redundant, horizontally scalable and optimized for the type of work it's doing.

You definitely **don't** want your app to hang or to become unusable whenever someone screws something up.

Answer (score 3):

High demanding processes should not be done on a web request.

What you should approach for example is using queues.
That way, you allow the file upload and create a queue process to serve that, then the request is finish and a moment after the process starts on the server, but the user got the request back.

Then you could consider to configure the queue with low CPU priority, or you could add sleep times between the data processing, allowing the CPU to serve other processes.

Or you could instead record the file after you upload it and have a console job configured to check every minute if there are pending data to be processed and then process a batch and allow the next batch to process on the next minute check, keeping the current line processed somewhere.

But, again, try to avoid doing those kind of long heavy processes on the web request, use the web request to get the information and then trigger the process separately.

Laravel have a very good support for either console jobs or queues in the framework.